# What is the string format to display the zeros (minimum 3 digits) after the decimal point in cshtml view page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

If the value is 3, then it should be display as 3.000, that is minimum to three decimals.

For eg., if the value is 2.05, then it is displaying as 2.05 as it is. But, it needs to be display as 2.050.

Code:

```
<span class="column-nos">@Html.Label("", String.Format("{0}", nos[i].Conversion.ToString()), new {@class = "numbers-conversion-value"})</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your values like this and do NOT convert the values into a string, drop the `ToString()`

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", the_value)
```

your code should look like this:

```
<span class="column-nos">@Html.Label("", 
    String.Format("{0:0.000}", nos[i].Conversion),
    new {@class = "numbers-conversion-value"})
</span>
```

Comment: I tried the above format `{0:0.000}`. Still the same result I am getting. If the value is 3, it is displaying as 3 and not as 3.000. But it needs to be display as 3.000.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed the part where you do the `ToString()`. Please see my updated answer.